# Do I need to comment out the line setting $base_url to be able to access a site with the https:// protocol?

Tags: 7, ssl

Initially the site was working under HTTP protocol and everything was fine. Then we bought an HTTPS certificate  and tried to open the site through HTTPS. All the css and js were broken. I opened the page source code and saw that all these files are loaded through HTTP.

```
@import url("http://...");
```

So, I opened /sites/default/settings.php. At first, I added `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` but it didn't work. Then I commented out `$base_url`.

```
//$base_url = 'http://sitename.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Afterward, both HTTP and HTTPS started to work.

Is it the correct way to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want both HTTP and HTTPS, or do you want HTTPS only?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Both

Comment: Why would you want both to work? You could risk duplicate indexing with search engines.

Comment: @erier "You could risk duplicate indexing with search engines." - yes, but it will decrease server load.